# Rotating Label inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I'm trying to rotate a UILabel 180° when the cell that contains it is being selected. I've tried setting the transform on the layer, I've tried a CABasicAnimation, and a UIView.animateWithDuration with no luck.

Anyone have any experience doing this in the past?

I can't call reloadData because the label is within an accordion cell and selection causes the accordion to open/close. reloadData overrides the animation from beginUpdates/endUpdates.

Here's what I've tried:

```
func rotate180Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

As well as this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
    cell.chevronLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
}
```

Here's my cell model, if it's relevant:

```
class SideMenuAccountTypeCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var accountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var abbreviationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var chevronLabel: UILabel!

    private (set) var items = [Item]()

    class Item {
        var isHidden: Bool
        var value: AnyObject

        init(_ hidden: Bool = true, value: AnyObject) {
            self.isHidden = hidden
            self.value = value
        }
    }

    class HeaderItem: Item {
        init (value: AnyObject) {
            super.init(false, value: value)
        }
    }

    func append(item: Item) {
        self.items.append(item)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        self.items.removeAll()
    }

    func expand(headerIndex: Int) {
        self.toggleVisible(headerIndex, isHidden: false)
    }

    func collapse(headerIndex: Int) {
        self.toggleVisible(headerIndex, isHidden: true)
    }

    private func toggleVisible(headerIndex: Int, isHidden: Bool) {
        var header = headerIndex
        header += 1

        while header < self.items.count && !(self.items[header] is HeaderItem) {
            self.items[header].isHidden = isHidden

            header += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue y'all:

Xcode auto-suggest put the method `tableView(tableView: tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)` in place of `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)`, which caused a new cell to be dequeued, overriding the animations.

Answer (score 2):

try this in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
    SideMenuAccountTypeCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   //transform to flips on y-axis 
   CATransform3D tfm = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

   //apply the transform before the animation so that the label remains in the same state on completion
   cell.chevronLabel.layer.transform = tfm; 

   CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
   animation.duration = 0.5f;
   animation.beginTime = 0.0f;
   //apply a little perspective 
   tfm.34 = 0.001f
   tfm.m14 = -0.001f;
   animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
   animation.fillMode =  kCAFillModeForwards;
   animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
   animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
   animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:tfm];
   [cell.chevronLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotateTheLabel"];
```

Comment: Same effect as the other solutions, I've tried -- which is to say, no effect. I've tried placing breakpoints, and the function *is* being fired. Is this an issue of the storyboard?

Comment: not at all... i have tested the above, using a tableview in a storyboard, with a prototype cell. I would check to ensure you have the correct cell reference. Also, a side effect of the above, is that the chevronLabel will remain transformed when the cell is reused, so you need to set the transform back when the cell is reused. with this in mind, are you seeing the transform in place after reloadData?  Try also moving the content of the function to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, to rule out the cell ref issue.

Comment: I am firing it in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. After further investigation, it seems that the transform *is* being applied, but the UI is not updating for some reason. I've tried calling `reloadData`, with no effect.